# how to upload image to server using dio flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dio

I want to upload an image from flutter to the server but I am failed. I tried with http package but it not worked. Then i found dio package useful and easy but I am getting following error when I use **FormData**.

**the name 'FormData' is defined in the libraries 'package:dio/src/form_data.dart (via package:dio/dio.dart)' and 'package:get/get_connect/http/src/multipart/form_data.dart'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.**

**code**

```
 static createNewSupervisor(String name, String email, String address,
      String site, String mobileNumber, String password, File? image) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = prefs.getString("token");
    var dio = Dio();
    var fd = FormData.fromMap({
      "full_name": name,
      "address": address,
      "mobile_no": mobileNumber,
      "email": email,
      "site_name": site,
      "password": password,
      // "image": baseimage,
    });
    var response = await dio.post("$baseURL/api/create",
        data: fd,
        options: Options(headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        } // set content-length
            ));
    print(response);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tring mimeType = mime(fileName);
  String mimee = mimeType.split('/')[0];
  String type = mimeType.split('/')[1];

  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";
  FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
   'file':await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath,
      filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType(mimee, type))
  });
  Response response = await dio
      .post('http://192.168.18.25:8080/test', data: formData)
      .catchError((e) => print(e.response.toString()));
```

The easiest method is to use the mime_type plugin from flutter.dev. Add this imports

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<String> uploadingImage(File file) async {
  String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
   "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, imageFile:imageFile),
  });
  response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
  return response.data['id'];
}
```